# Using Hosted Pool from TFS On-Premise

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to configure an on-premise TFS 2015 (Update 2) instance to make use of the hosted agent pool in a Visual Studio Team Services account?

All our builds / releases are currently done in-house, but to simplify the process of automated testing using clients and services hosted in Azure, we would like to move to VSTS-based agents (initially just for the release tasks, but possibly for build tasks later on).

The real desire here is to have our automated tests run outside our local network so our connection is not saturated with all the chatter of set-up / test run / tear-down against our cloud-hosted applications. These UI tests happen as part of our release process (using TFS Release Management).

I'm not 100% sure that configuring Releases to run on a hosted agent is the right approach to the problem, but it's what we're investigating for the time being anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hosted Pool currently works only with VSTS.

The only option for you at this point of time is to setup a VM with VSOAgent and configure it with TFS On-Prem. This will require your TFS to be exposed to internet (or just to the VM) so that the agent on Azure can configure itself.

Source - I am a Dev for the Hosted Pool Service.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information Harshil. We decided to put an agent on a VM in our Azure subscription and connect it to our own network via VPN. This seems to be working fine.

Comment: That's is an innovative idea. Thanks for letting me know.